# Increase timeout for the solution export in Dynamics 365 on-premises

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm trying to export the default solution from the CRM but every time after a few minutes I'm getting this error

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
```

In the Event Viewer I discovered the warning, which says the problem is in a timeout

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: HttpException 
Exception message: Request timed out.
```

So I'm wondering is it possible to increase the timeout for the solution export?

Comment: question: Why do you want to export default solution? It will contain everything from your particular env. In addition every env has default solution which has basic entities and customizations available.
Also increasing Timeout is bad idea. MS placed timeout for a purpose. I would suggest you think hard about exporting default solution is must or could be ignored.

Comment: @AnkUser I want to update CRM version, but it fails with some general error. I want to export the default solution and import it to the new organization (on test server). Then to export it from the test organization and compare these two solutions.

Comment: I guess your approach is wrong. what you are trying to do is somehow move the entire env except data to new orginization, In such cases you should copy your database to new org and then it shall have all the customizations including data into your new org. But I am not a profi here someone with more exp could add insights

Comment: @AnkUser I tried to import the database as an organization, it also failed. Thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

Several years ago I wrote a Console App to export the Default solution without having to worry about timeouts.

It has been a while since I used it. Based on your question I wanted to see if it still works.

I just ran it and it threw a exception saying that exporting the Default Solution is no longer supported:

[image: Exception Message]

The full message is:

> Exporting the default solution is not supported. To export components,
> add them to a custom solution.

Echoing what others have said, the organization import is the way to go, though it seems like you might need a Microsoft ticket to resolve the issue you're having with that.

Another idea, which I have not tried, would be to create a custom solution and use a tool like [XrmToolbox's Solution Components Mover](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/MsCrmTools.SolutionComponentsMover/) to migrate all the components from the Default solution into the custom solution and then see if you can export the custom solution.

Comment: I successfully exported the Default Solution month ago, there was no timeout error back then. Maybe I'll try it with the custom solution, thanks

Comment: Interesting, and were you able to import it to another org?

Comment: In the same state - no. The problem is when you export the Default Solution all the components of the Managed Solutions are exported with it. So I had to remove these components from the solution files manually. I've also met some problematic lines and errors (during the import) which could cause the organization update error. So I've successfully imported it, but I guess I removed to much components. I need to review it and see which components I'm able to return back.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Interesting that you successfully exported the Default Solution a month ago without a timeout. Considering that you need to remove components anyway, the custom solution is sounding better and better.

Comment: I think so too. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following documentation for CRM4 and CRM2011. As you are in an on-premises environment, check if you can find the same settings on your CRM server. I would always backup registry settings and web.config file before making a change.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/a-time-out-occurs-when-you-import-large-customization-files-into-microsoft-dynamics-crm-0825ac95-774d-0f58-0ddc-2f0e8507ad36

Also in an on-premises environment, it's doable to take a database backup of the MSCRM and redeploy into the same CRM server with multi-tenant support or a different server for setting up a UAT/Dev environment. It also includes dependent data as well.

To replicate an environment without running a redeployment process, you can create a new organization on the same server, import the exported solution which including only the customized components you've added/updated from the source CRM organization. Base data needs be moved over too to match the source CRM organization.

Comment: Thanks Jacqui, but I've solved the problem without exporting the solution. However, I can see that the link you shared is pretty useful